# JSF 1.2 - Insert new row into <t:dataTable> by using JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, jsf

I use javascript as below code:

```
function addARow() {
var cell;
var table = document.getElementById("x:dl");
var rowObj = table.tBodies[0].lastChild.cloneNode(true);
table.tBodies[0].appendChild(rowObj);
rowObj.cells[0].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].id = "x:dl:" + (table.rows.length - 2) + ":firstName";
rowObj.cells[0].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].name = rowObj.cells[0].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].id;
rowObj.cells[1].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].id = "x:dl:" + (table.rows.length - 2) + ":lastName";
rowObj.cells[1].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].name = rowObj.cells[1].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].id;
return false;
}
```

This is xHTML page:

```
<h:form id="x">
<t:dataTable id="dl" border="1" value="#{dynamicInputFieldController.nameList}" var="obj">
<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="First Name" />
</f:facet>
<h:inputText id="firstName" value="#{obj.firstName}" />
</h:column>
<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="Last Name" />
</f:facet>
<h:inputText id="lastName" value="#{obj.lastName}" />
</h:column>
</t:dataTable><br />

<h:commandButton value="Add A Row" onclick="addARow();return false" />
```

What I want is modify the datatable (add, remove, edit row data) at client side, after that, submit final data to server.

When I click on Add button, the last row was cloned. However, when I submit the form. Rows which just added are not submitted. But the value of current rows can be updated.

Is it possible with JSF 1.2?

Here is rendered HTML

```
<table id="x:dl" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="x:dl:tbody_element">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="x:dl:0:firstName" id="x:dl:0:firstName" type="text" value="AAAA" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="x:dl:0:lastName" id="x:dl:0:lastName" type="text" value="CCCC" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="x:dl:0:firstName" id="x:dl:1:firstName" submitName="x:dl:1:firstName" type="text" value="AAAA" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="x:dl:0:lastName" id="x:dl:1:lastName" submitName="x:dl:1:lastName" type="text" value="CCCC" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="x:dl:0:firstName" id="x:dl:2:firstName" submitName="x:dl:2:firstName" type="text" value="AAAA" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="x:dl:0:lastName" id="x:dl:2:lastName" submitName="x:dl:2:lastName" type="text" value="CCCC" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The 2nd and 3rd line were generated by above javascript.

Comment: What is the HTML that you get at the client?

Comment: I have updated in my question. Please note that the 2nd and 3rd line were generated by above javascript.